# Find string and convert to ASCII with PostScript

Tags: hex, ghostscript, postscript

I am a total newbie when it comes to postscript programming and I was trying to find a solution to my problem with the help of the geniuses in here.

I am a student that is currently working with a project where we are supposed to read something from a postscript file and place it in a new postscript file.

I want to edit a postscript file with the help of ghostscript to make an output with certain values I have picked out of the original postscript file.

Right now I have a file that does this, but I want to get the fonts that are embedded in a hexadecimal string and decode it so I get the ASCII symbol from it.

The original file have objects that look something like this

/g5 <1C60D8A8C9B64EDFFB83C6241DB110BEE5AB2FAD9D94B39ED5E81E7411B
66E9361DDE78FC667AB91EF9824>

And what I want to do is to pick them out and check them against some dictionary in the postscript code (systemdict???) and pick out its value.

Does anyone have something like this or an example to do this?

Right now my code to pick out the file starts something like this:
(%stdout) (w) file def

where I get the file and now I want to search for let's say the string "<1C60D8" and copy everything that is between this and the symbol ">"

After that I want to check what the hexadecimal code hides underneath it, which in this case is a "E" in Arial.

I want to extract the text so I can have it in a new file without the hexadecimal strings and in pure ASCII format. So  becomes a "P" for example.
After that I can make a software that picks out the "P" from the new postscript file and puts it on my homepage, and the final result is a homepage with everyones test results from the last exam for example.

Right now I am using ghostscript and the following command line which I found on the internet somewhere to extract the information in the file.

gswin32c.exe -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOPAUSE -sFONTPATH=C:\WINDOWS\Fonts -dBATCH extract.ps input.ps > output.ps

where extract.ps is the file in which I need to do some encoding to retrieve the hexadecimal string and encode it and lastly output it so it becomes an "normal" font, and also write in some coordinates of where they should lie.

If you have any knowlegde of how I should start that would be awesome. Right now I am thinking that this probably wont work and I'll have to do another approach like the other students, but since I found out that PostScript is a programming language I thought I could make it.

Right now I am  thinking I probably need to do something like this in the beginning.
(%Stdout)(w)
test{
     
     dup ????
     writestring
     check against systemdict?
     gcheck??
     
    } bind def
show test???

I am currently trying to read some literature that I found on the internet but it is very difficult!

If you know how to solve the problem, with an example, please let me know

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, in my opinion. PostScript *is* a programming language, so for general purposes you must use a PostScript interpreter to process it. Simply parsing the file, or any other similar approach, won't work in the general case (though it might for a simple file).

The original object you have quoted appears likely to be a glyph description in a font, probably a type 3 font, probably produced by Fontographer, but that's just guessing. Note that's a *glyph* not a font, a font is a collection of glyphs.

If I were doing this I would start by redefining the various PostScript operators. For example, if you redefine 'show' you can pick up the text as it is drawn (actually there are several kinds of show operator, you need to redefine them all). At the same time you can pick the font dictionary up, and you can arrange to output it to the file.

For example you might start with:

```
%!PS
% redefine.ps
%

/OutputFile (/out.txt) (w) file def

/show {
  OutputFile exch writestring
} bind def
```

Then run this command:

```
gswin32 redefine.ps input.ps
```

It will run `redefine.ps` which redefines the operators, then it will interpret `input.ps`. The redefined 'show' operator will write the string arguments to any 'show' operations to a file called `/out.txt`.

Obviously you can extend this to the other show operators. You can also take copies of the font dictionaries and then emit them as required. There's a bit of programming involved but here's an outline:

```
%!PS
%

/OutputFile (/out.txt) (w) file def

%% FontStore will be an array of font dictionaries
/FontStore 1 array def

/CheckFont {
  currentfont /FontName get %% Extract the name of the current font from the 
                            %% font dictionary 
  true                      %% termination condition
  FontStore {               %% forall is called for each member of the array
    /FontName get           %% get font name from stored font dictionary
    2 index                 %% copy the current font name from the stack
    eq                      %% See if they are the same
    {
      pop                   %% remove the 'false' condition
      false                 %% replace it with a 'true'
      exit                  %% and exit the loop
    } if
  } forall
  exch pop                  %% remove stored font name
  {
    %% make the array one bigger, copy the old array, add the current font dict.
  } if
} def

/show {
  CheckFont
  OutputFile exch writestring
} bind def

/showpage {
  %% Emit the fonts if required, potentially reorder the stored strings etc.
} bind def
```

Now whenever we execute a 'show', we will check to see if the current font is already stored, and store it if not. At the end of the page (when showpage is executed) we can do other things, like emitting the stored font dictionaries as fonts and so on.

One thing you will probably want to do is record the positions of the strings as they arrive at 'show', the currentpoint operator will give you the x.y position at the time show occurs. Instead of writing these to a file you may decide to store the string and its position in an array. In fact you might construct a dictionary with useful information:

```
/show {
  5 dict            %% make a dictionary
  begin             %% start it (put it on the dict stack as the current dict)
  /String exch def  %% put the string operand in the dict.
  currentpoint      %% get the current location
  /Y exch def       %% store in the dict
  /X exch def       %%
  currentfont       %% get current font dict
  /FontName get     %% get FontName
  /Font exch def    %% store name in dict
  currentfont       %% copy current dict to operand stack
  end               %% close dictionary and remove from dict stack
  %%
  %% In here, add the newly created dictionary to an array of dictionaries
  %%
} bind def
```

Now when you get to 'showpage', you have an array of fonts, and an array of string fragments with their properties. You can emit the fonts, then write out appropriate font selection criteria and strings to 'show' the strings in your output PostScript file.

There is much more you can do, you can capture the colour, you will need the CTM so you can calculate the font point size you need and so on.

Comment: Wow! That is alot of information! :D thanks alot, I will try and interpret exactly how you have written the code and I'll come back to you again for more questions :D

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but you never know when You might be online again, but could you help edit the text so it is easier to insert into a redefine.ps file? I have trouble editing out what is comments and what is code! :/
Best regards!

Comment: @Joe: your own question isn't well formatted either. How about improving **that** one first?  :-)

Comment: Reluctantly, you can use ken at spamcop.net.